# How can i use TWRequest for iOS 5 and iOS6

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, twitter

I am developing iPhone application having support iOS 5 and 6. I want to share Picture on twitter and the way i found is to use Twitter framework introduced in iOS 5.

But TWRequest is deprecated in iOS 6 and replaced by SLRequest in Social Framework which is not available in iOS 5. So how can i address this issue As TWRequest is deprecated in iOS 6 and SLRequest is not supported in iOS 5.
Any clue...

Comment: You can have a look at this [link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IPhone_iOS_6_Facebook_and_Twitter_Integration_using_SLRequest)

Comment: but this is only for iOS 6. How about iOS 5 support?

Comment: For iOS5, you can use `TWTweetComposeViewController` to present a prebuilt view modally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are going to use prebuilt `SLComposeViewController` to present a view modally for sharing on Twitter, you can use something like this

```
//Check for Social Framework availability (iOS 6)
if(NSClassFromString(@"SLComposeViewController") != nil){

    if([SLComposeViewController instanceMethodForSelector:@selector(isAvailableForServiceType)] != nil)
    {
        if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
        {
            NSLog(@"service available");
            SLComposeViewController *composeViewController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
            [composeViewController setInitialText:@"Testing Continues"];
            [composeViewController addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"]];
            [self presentViewController:composeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"service not available!");
        }
    }
}

else{
// For TWTweetComposeViewController (iOS 5)  
    if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]) {
        TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetVC = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
        [self presentModalViewController:tweetVC animated:YES];
        [tweetVC setInitialText:@"testing app"];
    } 
}
```

Else if you want to create your own request to share on twitter, after managing the user accounts on device, create a `SLRequest` as you want to

```
NSDictionary *message = @{@"status": @”Test message”};
NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json"];

SLRequest *postRequest = [SLRequest 
            requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                    requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                              URL:requestURL 
                       parameters:message];
```

Comment: Well in that case, it means i have to check explicitly i.e 
if(iOS5)
{
do this
}
else if(iOS6)
{
do this
}

Comment: @abdus: Pretty close; Zen's code tests capabilities rather than the OS version, but the effect is the same: it uses 6's view controller when it can, and the one that's been available since 5 otherwise. The only alternative is to use the one that's available on both, and is deprecated on one of them, unconditionally.